# delete hibernate entity question?

Tags: java, hibernate

i want to delete a row and cascade all foreign keys in hibernate
i am new to hibernate
and i want to know
if there's a method to delete an entity>> session.delete();
like the session.save and session.update methods in hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, hibernate's [`Session`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#delete%28java.lang.Object%29) has `delete(entity)` method.

If you want to cascade dependencies, you'd have to set `@*ToMany(cascade=CascadeType.DELETE)`

Comment: where to set this annotation on the primary key or the foreign key ?

Comment: not on the primary key. I wouldn't call it "on the foreign key", but yes.

Comment: If I want to delete only a single record, what is the way?

Comment: @Antoops - the delete method.

Comment: This related question is very interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210638/hibernate-delete-query