# Hibernate Delete query

Tags: java, hibernate

When I try to delete an entry from a db, using

```
session.delete(object)
```

then I can the following:

1) If the row is present in DB then two SQL queries are getting executed: A select and then a delete

2) If the row is not present in the DB then only the select query is getting executed

But again this is not the case for update. Irrespective of the presence of DB row, only the update query is getting executed.

Please let me know why this kind of behaviour for delete operation. Isn't it a performance issue since two queries are getting hit rather than one?

**Edit:**

I am using hibernate 3.2.5

**Sample code:**

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("student.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setFirstName("AAA");
    student.setLastName("BBB");
    student.setCity("CCC");
    student.setState("DDD");
    student.setCountry("EEE");
    student.setId("FFF");
    session.delete(student);
    session.flush();
            session.close();
```

**cfg.xml**

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">system</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">XXX</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl</property>      
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">30</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>    
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

**hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.infy.model.Student" table="STUDENT">
    <id name="id" column="ID">
        <generator class="assigned"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="firstName" type="string" column="FIRSTNAME"></property>
    <property name="lastName" type="string" column="LASTNAME"></property>
    <property name="city" type="string" column="CITY"></property>
    <property name="state" type="string" column="STATE"></property>
    <property name="country" type="string" column="COUNTRY"></property>        
</class>
```

Comment: Hibernate does sometimes make a select before an Update. It depends on what state the object is (persistent, transient or detached). To answer your specific question, it will be helpful to see your sample code.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The reason is that for deleting an object, Hibernate requires that the object is in persistent state. Thus, Hibernate first fetches the object (SELECT) and then removes it (DELETE).

Why Hibernate needs to fetch the object first? The reason is that Hibernate interceptors might be enabled (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html), and the object must be passed through these interceptors to complete its lifecycle. If rows are deleted directly in the database, the interceptor won't run.

On the other hand, it's possible to delete entities in one single SQL DELETE statement using bulk operations:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("delete Entity where id = X");
q.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: In that case, For update also the object should be in persisting state so it it can be fetched and then updated right?

Comment: No, for an object to be deleted it can be in transient, deattached or persistent state. I think that the point with your code is that you're creating a new object (Transient state) and then you delete it. The fact that you set an id for the object, doesn't cause the object to go from Transient to Persistent state (it's still a Transient object). For that reason, once the session.delete() is executed, it needs first to fetch the object, store it in the persistent context (first-level cache) and then remove it.

Comment: If you want to do a test, try to set your object with an id not present in DB. Then save it before deleting it, and then do the delete. You'll see how the delete doesn't require to do a SELECT because the object is already in the first-level cache (it's a persistent object).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I tried a save followed by a delete and it worked the way you suggested. I have a couple of questions: 1) When I assign the id for an object then is the object in Transient state or detached state? Because according to the doc, a transient state should not have the identifier assigned to the object right? 2) If I change the generator class from `assigned` to `native` then why is the delete not executing the select query before deleting the row? i.e. only delete query is executed without a prior select. Why like this?

Comment: When an object is created with new() is in Transient state. A transient object is an object which has never been persisted to DB (there's no row in DB representing the object). A detached object is an object that has been persisted at least once (so there's a row in DB that represents the object, thus the object has an id), and that is out of a session context. Assigning an id to a transient object doesn't make the object to become persistent, is the save() operation that does that. Then when the persistent object gets out of the session context, the object becomes detached.

Comment: Check out this response about the different states of an object in Hibernate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573739/what-are-detached-persistance-and-transient-object-in-hibernate This one is also good: http://learningviacode.blogspot.com.es/2012/02/hibernate-object-life-cycle.html About question 2) I'm a bit puzzle. What makes that no SELECt is being executed before DELETE is the fact that the object is in the session (I mean, the object was saved before deleting it). If that's not the case, could you paste your code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So is it like: I created an object, set its identifier to a value. Now if that identifier value is not present in DB then the object is Transient, again if it is present in DB then it is detached right? 

For the second one, no I have exactly the code I posted above, only change the generator from `assigned` to `native`. I don't have any save before delete.

Comment: The difference between transient and detached object is not only the presence of an id value, but more importantly if there's a row in the DB representing that object or not (no, in the case of transient; yes in the case of detached). Regarding the other question I need to write it in another comment :) (it's rather long)

Comment: First thing is that it doesn't make much sense to delete a transient object (there's not a row in the DB representing that object). In the case of strategy 'assigned', you assign an id to the object. When the delete is executed, Hibernate believes that the object was once stored in DB (because it has an ID), thus it retrieves the object (because of what I explained before) and then removes it. In the case of strategy 'native', you don't need to set an id to the object (that is handle by Hibernate). What it would happen if Hibernate tries to retrieve it? The SELECT performed would be...

Comment: ...something like: SELECT * FROM X WHERE id = null, which will always return empty. This query could be skipped, and Hibernate just executes DELETE. My believe (although I would need to check it against some docs), is that in the case of the transient object with strategy 'assigned' Hibernate believes the object is detached, and tries to fetched before deleting it. I insist that it doesn't make much sense to create a new instance and set an id, if what you want is to delete an object. The object must exist in the DB before deleting it, you should fetched with session.get(id) and then remove it

Answer (score 27):

To understand this peculiar behavior of hibernate, it is important to understand a few hibernate concepts -

**Hibernate Object States**

> Transient - An object is in transient status if it has been
>   instantiated and is still not associated with a Hibernate session.
>
> Persistent - A persistent instance has a representation in the
>   database and an identifier value. It might just have been saved or
>   loaded, however, it is by definition in the scope of a Session.
>
> Detached - A detached instance is an object that has been persistent,
>   but its Session has been closed.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-overview

**Transaction Write-Behind**

The next thing to understand is  'Transaction Write behind'. When objects attached to a hibernate session are modified they are not immediately propagated to the database. Hibernate does this for at least two different reasons.

> - To perform batch inserts and updates.
> - To propagate only the last change. If an object is updated more than once, it still fires only one update statement.

http://learningviacode.blogspot.com/2012/02/write-behind-technique-in-hibernate.html

**First Level Cache**

Hibernate has something called 'First Level Cache'. Whenever you pass an object to `save()`, `update()` or `saveOrUpdate()`, and whenever you retrieve an object using `load()`, `get()`, `list()`, `iterate()` or `scroll()`, that object is added to the internal cache of the Session. This is where it tracks changes to various objects.

**Hibernate Intercepters and Object Lifecycle Listeners -**

The Interceptor interface and listener callbacks from the session to the application, allow the application to inspect and/or manipulate properties of a persistent object before it is saved, updated, deleted or loaded.
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html#d0e3069

---

**This section Updated**

**Cascading**

Hibernate allows applications to define cascade relationships between associations. For example, `'cascade-delete'` from parent to child association will result in deletion of all children when a parent is deleted.

**So, why are these important.**

To be able to do transaction write-behind, to be able to track multiple changes to objects (object graphs) and to be able to execute lifecycle callbacks hibernate needs to know whether the object is `transient/detached` and it needs to have the object in it's first level cache before it makes any changes to the underlying object and associated relationships.

That's why hibernate **(sometimes)** issues a `'SELECT'` statement to load the object (if it's not already loaded) in to it's first level cache before it makes changes to it.

**Why does hibernate issue the 'SELECT' statement only sometimes?**

Hibernate issues a `'SELECT'` statement to determine what state the object is in. If the select statement returns an object, the object is in `detached` state and if it does not return an object, the object is in `transient` state.

**Coming to your scenario** -

**Delete** - The 'Delete' issued a SELECT statement because hibernate needs to know if the object exists in the database or not. If the object exists in the database, hibernate considers it as `detached` and then re-attches it to the session and processes delete lifecycle.

**Update** - Since you are explicitly calling `'Update'` instead of `'SaveOrUpdate'`, hibernate blindly assumes that the object is in `detached` state, re-attaches the given object to the session first level cache and processes the update lifecycle. If it turns out that the object does not exist in the database contrary to hibernate's assumption, an exception is thrown when session flushes.

**SaveOrUpdate** - If you call `'SaveOrUpdate'`, hibernate has to determine the state of the object, so it uses a SELECT statement to determine if the object is in `Transient/Detached` state. If the object is in `transient` state, it processes the `'insert'` lifecycle and if the object is in `detached` state, it processes the `'Update'` lifecycle.

Comment: I have posted a sample code, is the object in detached state?

Comment: Yes, it is in detached state. The initial thought would be that it is in 'Transient' state, but since you have assigned an id to the Student, hibernate would consider it as detached.

Comment: When I execute the above code with `generator = assigned`, then two queries are getting executed: select followed by delete but if I change the generator to `native` then only the delete is getting executed. So is it like the object is not in detached state when the generator is `native` even if I assign the Id?

Comment: If you use 'generator = assigned' and you do not specify an 'unsaved-value', hibernate has to always go to the database to determine whether an object is transient or detached. So, it has to issue a 'SELECT' statement. I'm not sure why it is not issuing a 'SELECT' statement when 'generator = native'. The only explanation is that hibernate is thinking that the object is in 'transient' instead of 'detached'. Could you post the code for your 'student.cfg.xml' file?

Comment: again, does not the same thing goes for an update? If I change the same code posted above  `delete` to `update` then also only one query is getting fired. Then why is it like the u`pdate` is in persistent state whereas `delete` is in detached state?

Comment: Sorry, please post student.hbm.xml or the hibernate configuration file for Student entity.

Comment: posted the hbm file, setting it to `assigned` as of now

Comment: Sorry, I'm mistaken about the update lifecycle. I've updated my answer to reflect the same. Basically, the SELECT statements are issued to determine whether the object is in 'Transient/Detached' state. The objects in transient state have different lifecycle events and different processing logic than the ones in detached state depending on the type of operation (save/update/delete) that we are trying to perform.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response :) I have some queries: 1) I can't see any exception printed in my console for update if the object is not present in DB. 2) If I change the generator from `assigned` to `native` then only the delete is executed without any select query. Why this different behavior for native then?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure but:

- If you call the delete method with a non transient object, this means first fetched the object from the DB. So it is normal to see a select statement. Perhaps in the end you see 2 select + 1 delete?
- If you call the delete method with a transient object, then it is possible that you have a `cascade="delete"` or something similar which requires to retrieve first the object so that "nested actions" can be performed if it is required.

---

**Edit:**
Calling delete() with a transient instance means doing something like that:

```
MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
entity.setId(1234);
session.delete(entity);
```

This will delete the row with id 1234, even if the object is a simple pojo not retrieved by Hibernate, not present in its session cache, not managed at all by Hibernate.

If you have an entity association Hibernate probably have to fetch the full entity so that it knows if the delete should be cascaded to associated entities.

Comment: All is in the javadoc. It's important to understand the lifecycle of an entity when using Hibernate. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#delete(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 1):

instead of using

> session.delete(object)

use

```
getHibernateTemplate().delete(object)
```

In both place for `select`   query and also for `delete` use `getHibernateTemplate()`

In `select` query you have to use `DetachedCriteria` or `Criteria`

Example for select query

```
List<foo> fooList = new ArrayList<foo>();
DetachedCriteria queryCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(foo.class);
queryCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("Column_name",restriction));
fooList = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(queryCriteria);
```

In hibernate avoid use of session,here I am not sure but problem occurs just because of session use

Comment: why to avoid using session? can you please provide some further inputs since your explanation is not clear

Comment: i am also using hibernate in my all applications,in past i also face problems for same table use with more then 2 query fire back to back. after few research i got solution as avoiding session use.it may not leave/drop/modify any value as we need or as we thought. and in session some times your data will be change/delete without your update/delete query(just because of session use). this is my experience with hibernate in last 2 year.

Comment: you check parent-child relation in db?, it may also give you an error. as 'open bounty' question i suppose you already checked for this.

Comment: where can I find the `getHibernateTemplate()` method? Can you please post the jar name for the same?

Comment: its part of spring framework - [download jar](http://www.findjar.com/jar/org.springframework/jars/spring-hibernate3-2.0-m4.jar.html)

Comment: Could you edit your post to add all the relevant information? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EntityManager` class. It is central interface for interacting with the persistence context and managing entity instances. It provides methods for CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations.

`entityManager.getReference` method is used to obtain a reference to the Object entity with the specified id. The getReference method is commonly used to obtain a lightweight proxy of an entity without immediately fetching its data from the database. This is useful for deletion operations, as it avoids unnecessary data retrieval.

By using `entityManager.remove`, you instruct the `JPA` provider (such as Hibernate) to schedule the deletion of the entity during the next flush or commit operation. The `JPA` provider will then generate the appropriate `SQL DELETE` statement to remove the entity from the database.

```
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Repository
public class SampleRepositoryImpl {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
...

    @Override
    public void delete(int id) {
        entityManager.remove(entityManager.getReference(Employee.class,id));
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**