# JPA 2.0 / Hibernate - why hibernate issue select count (*) query before delete

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, jpa-2.0, bidirectional

I am using spring-data with hibernate. I have a bidirectional mapping as follow:

```
public class Student {
   ...
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true,    mappedBy="student")
   private List<StudentLog> logs = newArrayList();  
   ...
}

public class StudentLog {
   .....
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID" , insertable = true, updatable = false, nullable =false)
    private Student student;
   .....
}
```

When I delete student using the JpaRepository: repo.delete(s.getId()); I can see the following queries

```
Hibernate: select count(*) as col_0_0_ from STUDENTS student0_ where student0_.ID=? and 1=1
Hibernate: select student0_.ID as ID1_2_2_, student0_.FIRST_NAME as FIRST2_2_2_,  educationh1_.STUDENT_ID as STUDENT6_2_4_, educationh1_.ID as ID1_0_4_, educationh1_.ID as  ID1_0_0_, educationh1_.CLASS as CLASS2_0_0_, educationh1_.LEVEL as LEVEL3_0_0_, educationh1_.PREDICTED_END_DATE as PREDICTE4_0_0_, educationh1_.START_DATE as START5_0_0_, educationh1_.STUDENT_ID as STUDENT6_0_0_, educationh1_.TERM as TERM7_0_0_, logs2_.STUDENT_ID as STUDENT3_2_5_, logs2_.ID as ID1_3_5_, logs2_.ID as ID1_3_1_, logs2_.LOG as LOG2_3_1_, logs2_.STUDENT_ID as STUDENT3_3_1_ from STUDENTS student0_ left outer join EDUCATION_HISTORY educationh1_ on student0_.ID=educationh1_.STUDENT_ID left outer join STUDENT_LOG logs2_ on student0_.ID=logs2_.STUDENT_ID where student0_.ID=?
Hibernate: delete from STUDENT_LOG where ID=?
Hibernate: delete from STUDENTS where ID=?
```

Any idea why hibernate issue the 2 select queries? Is it not possible to just issue the delete queries without the selects?

Thanks

Comment: I think this link answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13240979/2387977

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA only exposes a `remove(…)` method on `EntityManager` that takes the entity to be deleted. So for your call to `delete(…)` with the id we first check whether an entity with the id really existst (first query). We then materialize the object (second query) to eventually hand it to `EntityManager.remove(…)` (query 3 and 4).

Actually the `exists(…)` check is superfluous as we can simply check for `null` in the second step. I've created and fixed [DATAJPA-363](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-363), so that you should see one query less in the future.

Comment: One very good reason to bypass JPA altogether and go native (something I tend to do more and more often)