# Why does JpaRepository.delete() retrieve an entity before it will delete it?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When i delete an entity by using its id i get the following log output.

```
2020-09-19 17:07:35.536 DEBUG 14544 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select comment0_.id as id1_15_0_, comment0_.acceptedAsAnswer as accepted2_15_0_, comment0_.commentDate as commentD3_15_0_, comment0_.commenter_id as comment10_15_0_, comment0_.commenterIp as commente4_15_0_, comment0_.content as content5_15_0_, comment0_.dateDeleted as dateDele6_15_0_, comment0_.deleted as deleted7_15_0_, comment0_.deleter_id as deleter11_15_0_, comment0_.journal_entry_id as journal12_15_0_, comment0_.language_id as languag13_15_0_, comment0_.lastEditedOn as lastEdit8_15_0_, comment0_.likeTotal as likeTota9_15_0_, comment0_.owning_comment_id as owning_14_15_0_ from comments comment0_ where comment0_.id=?
2020-09-19 17:07:35.562 DEBUG 14544 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : delete from comments where id=?
```

I am building a webapplication that is using a database service from Amazon so every request that the app makes costs extra money. Why does spring retrieve the object first before deleting it and is there any way to stop it from doing this?

Comment: Kindly check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13240979/7976968. The question answered there already. The reason behind doing the select is that the hibernate needs to know if the object is in persistance state.

Comment: thanks guys, i understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Naim pointed out hibernate retrieves the object first because there might be interceptors present. Here is my solution for making a delete query directly to the database using a `JpaRepository` implementing repository.

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE id = :id")
void deleteById(@Param("id") Long id);
```

The custom method `deleteById` will not require the entity to be fetched first.